# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in reactjs due to state undeclaration?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
class Report extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reports: {
        chartslist: {
            charts: []
        },
      }, 
    };
    this._contractStoreChange = this._contractStoreChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {  
    let datapiechart = this.state.reports.chartslist.charts[3] || {};

    const config = {
      chart: {
        type: datapiechart.chart.type
      },
      series:
        [{data:datapiechart.seriesPie.series,
          name:"clients"
      }]
    };

    return (
       <div > 
         <ReactHighcharts config={config}></ReactHighcharts>
       </div>
    )
}
 }
```

I'm getting this error:

[image: image from error]

How to declare the type in the state. i guess it is showing because of not declaring in state. Can any one help in declaring the type in state.

Comment: do you want to know how to put objects in an array?

Comment: becuase you have not added any data to the charts object but you are trying to access the 3rd boject in the array which is empty

Comment: @sujit-warrier: this does not break thanks to the default value (` || {}`), but the default object is not enough to get .chart.type and .seriesPie.series.

Comment: @kLabz exactly what im saying. he needs to add something to the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some  code sanitisation

```
type: datapiechart.chart && datapiechart.chart.type
```

**Update :**

consider this example.

```
var a  = { "testName": "please evalute when true"}


1. true && a //return {testTitle: "please evalute when true"}
```

***true*** means any expression that evaluate to true.In your case its existence of an Object `datapiechart.chart` which should not be `null/undefined`.

```
2. false && a //return false
```

***false*** : if `datapiechart.chart` is `null/undefined`